# Extraer filas individuales y concatenarlas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un `DataFrame` con varias filas; lo que necesito es poder *empaquetarlas* en un número variable de ellas; por ejemplo, si a la entrada tengo

> [ [ 1, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 2, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 3, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 4, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 5, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 6, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 7, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 8, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 9, 0, 0 ] ]

en *paquetes* de 2, debería quedarme algo así:

> [ [ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ]
>   [2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ] ]

Y en *paquetes* de 3, algo así:

> [ [ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 ]
>   [2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0 ]
>   [ 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ]

Ahora mismo estoy intentado esto:

```
def packageData( pool: pd.DataFrame, joinCount: int ):
    if joinCount < 1:
        raise Exception( "Bad <joinCount>, must be >= 1" )

    if joinCount == 1:
        return pool

    subIndexes = list( range( joinCount ) )
    pool = pd.DataFrame( pool )
    result = pd.DataFrame( )

    subIndexes.reverse( )

    for rowIdx in range( joinCount - 1, len( pool ) ):
        sub = pd.DataFrame( pool.iloc[rowIdx - subIndexes[0]] ).T

        for subIndex in subIndexes[1:]:
            #orig = pd.DataFrame( [ sub.iloc[ 0 ] ] )
            toAppend = pd.DataFrame( pool.iloc[rowIdx - subIndex] ).T
            #sub = pd.concat( [ orig, toAppend ], axis = 1 )
            sub = pd.concat( [ sub.iloc[0], toAppend.iloc[0]], axis = 0, ignore_index = True ).T

        result = pd.concat( [ result, sub ], axis = 1, ignore_index = True ).T
        pass


    return result


def makeTestData( ):
    result = [ ]

    for idx in range( 1, 25 ):
        result.append( ( idx, 0, 0, ) )

    return pd.DataFrame( result, columns = ( "0", "1", "2", ) )


packageData( makeTestData( ), 3 )
```

<sub>**Nota**: ahora mismo voy por la vigésimo cuatragésima prueba, igual el código es un poco absurdo.</sub>

Aparte de que no funciona (da error en ejecución), me parece que me estoy complicando la cabeza demasiado.

¿ Como puedo hacer lo que necesito ?

Comment: en donde te sa error de ejecucion?

Comment: define que es un paquete de 2 o de 3?

Comment: creo que la solucion debe ser mas simple, tengo una idea para responderte pero no estoy seguro que funcione y no tengo como probarlo XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar algo como esto:

```py
def packageData(pool: pd.DataFrame, joinCount: int):
    # Contamos cuántas filas necesitamos generar
    resultingRows = len(df) - joinCount + 1
    # Generamos listas que serán las filas de nuestro df
    packs = (pool.iloc[i:i + joinCount].to_numpy().flatten()
             for i in range(resultingRows))

    # Convertimos nuestra lista de listas en un df
    return pd.DataFrame(packs)
```

Seleccionamos la cantidad de filas que queremos que conformen la fila i-ésima.
En nuestro caso avanzaremos tantas como se nos indique.
Para transformar varias filas en una lista usamos el método [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).
Una vez que tenemos tantas listas (en realidad [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy-ndarray) unidimensionales) como filas las convertimos de nuevo en un DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas el resultado es equivalente a concatenar el dataframe con el mismo `joinCount` veces  en el eje 1, pero desplazando la ventana de filas a usar, siendo la primera `pool[0: numero_de_filas_de_pool - join_count]`, la segunda `pool[1: numero_de_filas_de_pool - (join_count - 1)]`, etc.

Una forma simple de conseguirlo es usando `numpy.concatenate` y meros rebanados del array subyacente al DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



def package_data(pool: pd.DataFrame, join_count: int) -> pd.DataFrame():
    nr = pool.shape[0]
    pool_arr = pool.to_numpy()
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.concatenate(
            [pool_arr[i: nr - (join_count - i)] for i in range(join_count)],
            axis=1)
        )
```

> ```
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame([(idx, 0, 0) for idx in range(1, 25)], columns=("0", "1", "2"))
>
> >>> df
>  
>      0  1  2
> 0    1  0  0
> 1    2  0  0
> 2    3  0  0
> 3    4  0  0
> 4    5  0  0
> 5    6  0  0
> 6    7  0  0
> 7    8  0  0
> 8    9  0  0
> 9   10  0  0
> 10  11  0  0
> 11  12  0  0
> 12  13  0  0
> 13  14  0  0
> 14  15  0  0
> 15  16  0  0
> 16  17  0  0
> 17  18  0  0
> 18  19  0  0
> 19  20  0  0
> 20  21  0  0
> 21  22  0  0
> 22  23  0  0
> 23  24  0  0
>
> >>> package_data(df, 2)
>
>      0  1  2   3  4  5
> 0    1  0  0   2  0  0
> 1    2  0  0   3  0  0
> 2    3  0  0   4  0  0
> 3    4  0  0   5  0  0
> 4    5  0  0   6  0  0
> 5    6  0  0   7  0  0
> 6    7  0  0   8  0  0
> 7    8  0  0   9  0  0
> 8    9  0  0  10  0  0
> 9   10  0  0  11  0  0
> 10  11  0  0  12  0  0
> 11  12  0  0  13  0  0
> 12  13  0  0  14  0  0
> 13  14  0  0  15  0  0
> 14  15  0  0  16  0  0
> 15  16  0  0  17  0  0
> 16  17  0  0  18  0  0
> 17  18  0  0  19  0  0
> 18  19  0  0  20  0  0
> 19  20  0  0  21  0  0
> 20  21  0  0  22  0  0
> 21  22  0  0  23  0  0
>
> >>> package_data(df, 3)
>
>      0  1  2   3  4  5   6  7  8
> 0    1  0  0   2  0  0   3  0  0
> 1    2  0  0   3  0  0   4  0  0
> 2    3  0  0   4  0  0   5  0  0
> 3    4  0  0   5  0  0   6  0  0
> 4    5  0  0   6  0  0   7  0  0
> 5    6  0  0   7  0  0   8  0  0
> 6    7  0  0   8  0  0   9  0  0
> 7    8  0  0   9  0  0  10  0  0
> 8    9  0  0  10  0  0  11  0  0
> 9   10  0  0  11  0  0  12  0  0
> 10  11  0  0  12  0  0  13  0  0
> 11  12  0  0  13  0  0  14  0  0
> 12  13  0  0  14  0  0  15  0  0
> 13  14  0  0  15  0  0  16  0  0
> 14  15  0  0  16  0  0  17  0  0
> 15  16  0  0  17  0  0  18  0  0
> 16  17  0  0  18  0  0  19  0  0
> 17  18  0  0  19  0  0  20  0  0
> 18  19  0  0  20  0  0  21  0  0
> 19  20  0  0  21  0  0  22  0  0
> 20  21  0  0  22  0  0  23  0  0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Para la cambiar las dimensiones de una lista o de una DataFrame te recomiendo utilizar la librería numpy que contiene muchas funciones útiles para este tipo de acciones.

Para hacer lo que pides únicamente hay que definir una función que nos devuelva el resultado de juntar varias filas y aplanarlas con la función np.array.flatten().

```
def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size):
    arrays = [df.values[i:i+chunk_size].flatten() for i in range(0, len(df)-chunk_size+1)]
    return np.array(arrays)

chunk_size = 2
result_array = split_dataframe(df, chunk_size)
```

Comment: Según la [documentación de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), es preferible usar [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) en vez de `values`.